# Confusion over recovery of privatekey in DSA signature when duplicate value of r occurs

Tags: dsa

In DSA signature where signing is done via

$$s = k^{-1}(H(m) + xr) \mod{q} $$

I understand why if two messages singed by the same private key $x$ use the same $k$ value you can recover the private key

But I've read various comments and answers that say if two messages signed by the same private key have the same $r$ value that is all that is needed to recover the private key, and I don't understand how that is possible

Since $$r = (g^k \mod{p}) \mod{q}$$

how does two $r$'s being equal give you the same $k$? Shouldn't there be something like $\lfloor p/ q\rfloor$ different $k$'s that result in the same $r$ since $g$ is a generator for the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$? They won't all have the same inverse modulo $q$ so how do you solve the two equations since there are three unkowns, $k_1^{-1}, k_2^{-1}, x$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that $g$ is not the generator of the full cyclic group $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*$, but of a cyclic subgroup of order $q$. As such then we can only see at most $q$ possible $r$ values and we expect to see any given $r\pmod q$ value roughly Poisson(1) times.This does mean that we do expect roughly $(1-2/e)q$ $r$ values corresponding to more than one $k$.

However, even if we were guaranteed to always choose different $k$ values with each signature, we would not expect to see a repeated $r$ value until $\sqrt q$ signatures had been generated (by the birthday paradox). In reality, this is a very unlikely number of signatures for a cryptographic sized $q$ and so any repeat is much more likely to be attributable to a repeated $k$ value due to an implementation error of some sort. This is not a theorem, but a reliable rule of thumb.

Comment: ok, that makes me feel better, I'm not crazy! :) Thanks for taking the time to answer!